# linking fortran code to library

Tags: linux, linker, gfortran

I'm trying to link my main code to a library

main code:

```
program main1
call test1
end program main1
```

library:

```
subroutine test1
print*,'ok'
end subroutine test1
```

then I create library :

```
gfortran -shared -fPIC -o lib1.so 1.f90
```

and compile main code

```
gfortran -c main.f90
```

and link

```
gfortran main.o lib1.so
```

but I've got this error :

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: lib1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your example does work, but you are just missing a small thing: When using a shared library, your program (main.f90 / a.out) will try to find the linked library in one of the library folders (such as `/lib*`, `/usr/lib*` or `/usr/local/lib*`).

If you want to specify another folder for your shared library (for example for testing/debugging), you can use the  enviroment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to "tell" linux another place to look for shared libraries.

So, assuming you wrote your program in the folder `/home/mojijoon/fortran` you can get the correct output after setting the library path by:

```
$: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/mojijoon/fortran
$: ./a.out
  ok
```

You can find more information on shared libraries (and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH enviromental variable) here:
[tldp.org - shared libraries](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)